# Dual Wan - Failover not working

Tags: wan, failover

I have 2 ISPs connected to a dual wan Linksys LRT224.

[image]

On the LRT224 I configured the failover as shown:

[image]

However, failover does not work if WAN1 fails (fiber optic is down), if  physically I disconnect the WAN1 cable, WAN2 starts working but I must disconnect the cable to the failover work. Looking at the LRT224 status, I found that WAN2 has not gotten any IP as shown in the pic.

[image]

If I configure the router as load balance:

[image]

WAN2 gets an IP:

[image]

But navigation is sometimes slow. I do not understand why failover does not work as expected: if WAN1 fails why I must disconnect the ethernet cable from the LRT224 to "activate" WAN2?

I am not a networking expert, I just understand the basics.

Comment: You did not indicate, in the body of your question, that you had contacted Linksys.  That is important information.  Update your question.

Answer (score 2):

Solution was adding the ISP host and removing other options, my test was made disconnecting the fiber from the router, hope this works in a real word scenario:

[image]